# I'm doing clustering using k-maps but in the end all the vales come in the same cluster

Tags: algorithms, clustering

[This is the data im working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcYFT.png)

[Using cases 6,9,15 as the initial cluster centers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y6gH.png)

[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYBsr.png)
Using the mean values of the clusters insted of the initial values.
There some change in the clustering.

[Third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAb6b.png)I repeated the same steps but I dont think this should be the table.
I'm using the formula SUMXMY2 in the excel cell for sum of squared differences.